# Is this proof of uniform convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, maxima-minima

So I have that $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^3}, n=1,2,3.. \quad$ and the question is to calculate $f'_n$, find the max and min value of $f_n$ on $R$ and show that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $R$. Here is how I have done: 
$f'_n(x)=\frac{1-2nx^3}{(1+nx^3)^2}$ and we get that $f'_n(x)=0$ for $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n}}$ and this is a local maximum since we have that $lim_{x^- \to \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{-n}}}f_n = \infty$ and vice versa $lim_{x^+ \to \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{-n}}}f_n = -\infty \quad$ 
With  $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2n}}$ I get that $f_n=\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{2n}}$ 
With this information I can show that 
$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le max\{\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{2n}}, \frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{2m}} \} \quad$ and so $\forall \epsilon >0$, we can choose $N$  s.t. $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$ and $\forall n,m \ge N$ we get:   
$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \epsilon\quad \forall x\in R$ which shows that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $R$ 
Are my calculations correct? I am more unsure about my proof of uniform convergence. Can someboy help with that?

Comment: I don't think you copied your problem correctly, because not only is your proof wrong, but the statement is false too. It is easy to see that $f_n$ has an infinite discontinuity at $x = -n^{1/3}$ and is continuous everywhere else. Therefore, the uniform distance between any two functions $f_m$ and $f_n$ with $m \neq n$ is actually infinite.

Comment: To correct a small typo in the previous comment: the discontinuity is at $x = -n^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I appreciate it. I just realized that I infact did copy wrong function. smh